# Jquery: Get value from dynamic attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I’m adding a total amount value to a DIV through a jQuery Ajax call everytime I add a new item to a shopping cart. I need this value to be a part of a difference calculation (`payment-totalAmount`), but I’m having troubles getting the `totalAmount` value.

I set the total amount in the function called `SetTotalAmount` and then I try to get the value from the DIV tag in the `submitPayment` actionevent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submitPayment").click(function(){
        var paymentAmount = $("#paymentAmount").val();
        var totalAmount = $("#totalTillAmount").val();
        var difference = (paymentAmount-totalAmount);

        $("#paymentTillAmount").html("betalt: "+paymentAmount);
        //$("#totalTillAmount").html("total: "+totalAmount);

        $("#difference").html("Tilbage: "+difference);

        $("#paymentInfo").show('slow');

    });

});


function SetTotalAmount()
{
    $.post("Controller/TillController.php?action=3", 
            function(data)
            {
                $("#totalAmount").html(data);
                $("#totalTillAmount").html(data);
            }
    );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to parse strings before performing calculations:

```
var paymentAmount = parseFloat($("#paymentAmount").text());
var totalAmount = parseFloat($("#totalTillAmount").text());
```

Also as `#totalTillAmount` is a `div` you may need to use the [text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) function instead of [val](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) (which is used for `input` elements) to read it's contents.